# Sum consecutive numbers in a list. Python

Tags: python, function, numbers, sum

i'm trying to sum consecutive numbers in a list while keeping the first one the same.

so in this case 5 would stay 5, 10 would be 10 + 5 (15), and 15 would be 15 + 10 + 5 (30)

```
x = [5,10,15]
y = []

for value in x:
   y.append(...)

print y

[5,15,30]
```

Comment: Can you change the accepted answer please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want [`itertools.accumulate()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) (added in Python 3.2). Nothing extra needed, already implemented for you.

In earlier versions of Python where this doesn't exist, you can use the pure python implementation given:

```
def accumulate(iterable, func=operator.add):
    'Return running totals'
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5]) --> 1 3 6 10 15
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5], operator.mul) --> 1 2 6 24 120
    it = iter(iterable)
    total = next(it)
    yield total
    for element in it:
        total = func(total, element)
        yield total
```

This will work perfectly with any iterable, lazily and efficiently. The `itertools` implementation is implemented at a lower level, and therefore even faster.

If you want it as a list, then naturally just use the `list()` built-in: `list(accumulate(x))`.

Answer (score 6):

```
y = [sum(x[:i+1]) for i in range(len(x))]
```

Comment: This requires the creation of a ton of sublists, and only works on sequences, not arbitrary iterables. It's also reinventing the wheel in 3.2+.

Comment: @draconisthe0ry:  Beware of the performance characteristics of this approach as it becomes quite slow when the list is long.  Not only does it create `len(x)` sublists, it sums each sublist each time, rather than adding the latest value to the running sum.  Lattyware's answer is the pythonic solution.

Answer (score 4):

With numpy.cumsum:

```
In[1]: import numpy as np
In[2]: x = [5,10,15]
In[3]: x = np.array(x)
In[4]: y = x.cumsum()
In[5]: y
Out[6]: array([ 5, 15, 30])
```

I am using Python 3.4

Answer (score 1):

As in sum all the elements up to the element you're on?

```
x = [5,10,15]
y = [sum(x[:i+1]) for i in range(len(x))]
```

Comment: no. this one makes [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]] . thanks tho