# python symbol for consecutive numbers

Tags: python, formula

I have stumbled across a problem that requires the use of the "Unknown formula".

Referenced here: http://www.murderousmaths.co.uk/books/unknownform.htm

I have looked high and low and have not found an equivalent python symbol for "!" in the manner the author is using it.

```
# Example of authors use of '!'
5! == 5x4x3x2x1
```

I know that I could use a loop to create it, like in this post: [Sum consecutive numbers in a list. Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074920/sum-consecutive-numbers-in-a-list-python)

But I am hoping to make this a learning moment.

---

### edit

There is a great thread about factorials ([Function for Factorial in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136447/function-for-factorial-in-python)), however I much prefer The solution answer provided below.  Very clear and concise.

Comment: [`math.factorial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=factorial#math.factorial)

Comment: The ! represents the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial). It’s in Python as [`math.factorial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.factorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a mathematical function called a [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial), and is covered in depth in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136447/function-for-factorial-in-python).

The simplest approach is:

```
import math
math.factorial(5)
```

A functional approach:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator
answer = reduce(operator.mul, range(1, 6))
```

Loop approach:

```
answer = 1
for i in range(5):
    answer *= i+1
```

[Another answer uses a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062600/create-list-of-factorials-using-list-comprehension).

Comment: Brilliant!  That is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: If you're going to use `functools`, at least use `operator.mul`... :)

Comment: Or with numpy: `import numpy as np; 
def factorial(n): return np.product(np.array(range(1, n + 1)))`

Comment: @Tomothy32 I edited the answer with your suggestion